# Proper build trigger rule for a TFS path in TeamCity

Tags: tfs, teamcity

I am trying to trigger a build only on commits to the trunk rather than the branches.  When I make the build trigger on any VCS commit it works fine but I cannot seem to get the rule right to trigger only on commits to MAIN/source by any user.  What is the proper rule declaration to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. If you don't want to build from other branches, you can edit the VCS Root and clear out the "Branch specification" field.

If you want to be able to build from other branches, you create a [Branch Filter](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-BranchFilter) on your VCS Trigger. Try this:

```
+:<default>
```